Декораторы Python. Применение при вызове функции
Можно ли применить декоратор при вызове функции, а не при определении?

Да, тоже как один из вариантов:
def decorator(function):
    def wrapper(*args):
        print("Это начало декоратора")
        print(function(*args))
        print("А это конец декоратора")

    return wrapper


def func(x):
    return x * 2


decorated_func = decorator(func)
decorated_func(10)

